# Variance of resampled sample average: where did I go wrong?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Suppose I have an original sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and I generate $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ where each $Y_i$ is sampled from the uniform distribution on $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ and $Y_i$'s are independent. I'm trying to compute the variance of $Z=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iY_i$ in two ways but I don't get the same answer. I think Method 1 below is correct but I can't figure out where I have erred in Method 2.

**Method 1**: First, setting $\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iX_i$, I set out to compute $E(Y_i)$ and $E(Y_i^2)$:
$$
E(Y_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iX_i=\mu;\quad E(Y_i^2)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iX_i^2
$$
and so $\text{Var}(Y_i)=E(Y_i^2)-E(Y_i)^2$. Because $Z=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iY_i$ and the $Y_i$ are independent, it follows that $\text{Var}(Z)=\frac{\text{Var}(Y_i)}{n}=\frac{E(Y_i^2)}{n}-\frac{\mu^2}{n}$.

**Method 2**: We have
$$
E(Z)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iE(Y_i)=\frac{1}{n}n\mu=\mu;\\
E(Z^2)=\frac{1}{n^2}E\left[\left(\sum_iY_i\right)^2\right]=\frac{1}{n}E(Y_i^2).
$$
Then: $\text{Var}(Z)=E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2=\frac{E(Y_i^2)}{n}-\mu^2$.

Perhaps you can point out my mistake in an answer so that I can give you proper rep and I can close the question.

Comment: The mistake is that $(Y_i)$ is not independent but only independent conditionally on $(X_k)$.

Comment: @Did Oh that's unfortunate. So is either of my approaches correct at all? Both use a claim of independence at some point. How do I fix this please?

Comment: Call $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and use $$E(Y_i^2\mid X)=\frac1n\sum_kX_k^2\quad E(Y_i\mid X)=\frac1n\sum_kX_k\quad E(Y_iY_j\mid X)=E(Y_i\mid X)E(Y_j\mid X)$$ for every $i\ne j$ to compute $$E(Z^2\mid X),$$ and finally deduce $$E(Z^2)=E(E(Z^2\mid X)).$$

Comment: @ Did I think that if I treat $X$'s as fixed (exogenous) then it's okay to claim independence for $Y$'s. What you have shown is a proper way to do the unconditional variance of $Z$ but for my case, conditional is enough for now. It turns out that my mistake is far sillier that the conditional v.s. unconditional subtlety. I didn't realize it until I saw your expression for $E(Y_iY_j|X)$.

Comment: 1. No space between `@` and `username` please. 2. Please learn the proper language for conditioning matters, which does not include "exogenous" and requires to mention "conditional independence" and not independence when the former holds but not the latter. 3. I conjecture that your mistake is exactly related to what I describe. 4. If my comment helped you, all the better.

Comment: @Did All points are well-taken. It's unfortunate but I have never had formal probability theory so I lack the proper and precise formalism. Can you recommend a text or two for self-studying to have a better grasp of the things we have discussed here?

Comment: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html http://www.amazon.com/dp/0131856626 https://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/EP4A/EP4A.html

Answer (score 1):

My mistake in Method 2 is in the step:
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}E\left[\left(\sum_iY_i\right)^2\right]{\color{red}=}\frac{1}{n}E(Y_i^2).
$$
For $i\neq j$, we have $E(Y_iY_j)=\mu^2$ and so
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n^2}E\left[\left(\sum_iY_i\right)^2\right]&=\frac{1}{n^2}(n E(Y_i^2)+\sum_{i\neq j}E(Y_iY_j))\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(n E(Y_i^2)+n(n-1)\mu^2\right).
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$
\text{Var}(Z)=E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2=\frac{E(Y_i^2)+(n-1)\mu^2}{n}-\mu^2=\frac{E(Y_i^2)-\mu^2}{n}
$$
which now agrees with the answer in Method 1.